# Creating QPixmaps in a loop uses a high amount of RAM

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Creating QPixmaps are using a large amount of RAM.

I am creating about 50 QLabels in a loop and adding a photo as a cover image.

Here is a small, basic part of the code that I'm using:

```
def main(self):
    for i in os.listdir(self.directory) * 10:
        image = QLabel(self.labelArea)
    
        image.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage("{}/{}".format(self.directory , i))))
```

Suppose the current RAM is 1400MB. When I run the above, it goes upto 2500MB. That's insane!

Second Code:

```
def main():
    for i in os.listdir(self.directory) * 10:
        image = QLabel(self.labelArea)
    
        # image.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage("{}/{}".format(self.directory , i))))
```

On commenting the second line of the for loop, the RAM goes upto 1490Mb only! (From 1400MB)

Is there any problem in the provided code or I am messing up in rest of the code?

As requested, Minimal Reproducible Example

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

def createUi():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    
    imagesArea = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
    
    window.setCentralWidget(imagesArea)
    
    imagesArea.setGeometry(QRect(0 , 0 , 1980 , 1080))
    
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    
    layout.setSpacing(20)
    
    imagesArea.setLayout(layout)
        
    for i in ["sample.jpg"] * 10:
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        label.setFixedSize(QSize(400 , 400))
        
        label.setPixmap(QPixmap(i))
        
        label.setScaledContents(True)
        
        layout.addWidget(label)
        
    print("DONE <3")
        
    window.show()
    
    imagesArea.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   createUi()
```

My goal is to show all the images in a column

"my_img.png" is of 1000x800 px resolution.

This code does uses 20MB but eventually goes down after the for loop

If I talk about image of 1980x1080 resolution, it takes about 200 MB for only 10 images!

Comment: 1) Do not use QImage but directly QPixmap: `image.setPixmap(QPixmap("{}/{}".format(self.directory , i)))`, 2) How many does each image or all images weight?

Comment: 1) No the same problem :^) . 2)Most of them are of 1980x1080

Comment: Is there any alternative for QPixmap?

Comment: There is no alternative to QPixmap but I think there may be an alternative to your background problem (I think you have an XY problem). Is it necessary to show loading all the images at once? I pointed this out since they are large images so it is easy to assume that they will occupy the entire screen (or at least a part of it) so it does not make sense to load all the images at once but on demand. If you want more help you must provide a [MRE] and explain your underlying objective.

Comment: No its not necessary. Showing one after other will do the trick. Okay i will provide one. I will edit the question with MRE

Comment: @0xsapphir3 consider that, roughly speaking, each image generally occupies *at least* 4 bytes per pixel in memory (the file format compression is just for storing, what is *shown on the screen* is stored in memory as not compressed). You're using full HD pictures, which translates in about 8MB for each image. That gets you easily over 1GB of memory with just a little more than 100 images.

Comment: @eyllanesc, i guess you were right. Setting a pixmap of high resolution images certainly takes a lot of ram :^). I tried using less resolution images (like 1000x800). Firstly, it took 200MB and then gradually decreased by about 150MB. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @musicamante, Yeah all of them are HD. Probably it is using. Is there any solution? And moreover, using 1GB of ram makes my pc more heated :^)

Comment: @0xsapphir there's no "solution" to the matter at hand: every image that you want to keep in memory occupies it's *raw image* size. There are solutions to the way those images will be actually shown in order to optimize both memory and speed, but since there are virtually infinite alternatives and solutions, we cannot help you until you provide a [mre] as requested.

Comment: Yeah I am providing minimal reproducible example. It may take 2 - 3 min

Comment: Check it out! I have added minimal reproducible exmaple

Comment: @0xsapphir3 how is the user supposed to view *all* the images and/or switch between them? Why are you using a QLabel as a container for the other labels? Also, you're setting that "imagesArea" as child of the main window, but did not set it as its [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details) (which isn't considered as a supported/suggested practice). (Please use @username)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234798/discussion-between-0xsapphir3-and-musicamante).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @musicamante and @eyllanesc for helping me in figuring out the answer.

I tried resizing the image with the help of PIL module  and i looks like it is doing the trick (A bit slow, but i will consider it)

An update in answer after @eyllanesc's comment:

Updated Answer:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PIL import Image , ImageQt

def createUi():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    
    imagesArea = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
    
    window.setCentralWidget(imagesArea)
    
    imagesArea.setGeometry(QRect(0 , 0 , 1980 , 1080))
    
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    
    layout.setSpacing(20)
    
    imagesArea.setLayout(layout)
        
    for i in ["sample.jpg"] * 10:
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        label.setFixedSize(QSize(400 , 400))
        
        label.setPixmap(QPixmap(i).scaled(400 , 400))
        
        label.setScaledContents(True)
        
        layout.addWidget(label)
                
    window.show()
    
    imagesArea.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   createUi()
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use PIL to resize an image since QPixmap can do it directly:  `label.setPixmap(QPixmap(i).scaled(400 , 400))`

Comment: Thats even faster and better than PIL.Image.resize()